# Spring-boot application - External properties not loaded when jar execute with su -

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an application in spring-boot 2.2.4

When I launch the application like this :

> java -jar ../batch-pj-clean-nas/target/batch-pj-clean-nas-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dconfig.location=application.properties

Everything is ok.

When I try like that :

```
su - sbert -c "java -jar /home/sbert/workspace/pj/batch-pj-clean-nas/target/batch-pj-clean-nas-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dconfig.location=application.properties"
```

the properties is not loaded

> Could not resolve placeholder 'nas.base.directory' in value "${nas.base.directory}"

I try with OS ubuntu, RH8
and spring-boot 2.2.4 or 2.1.3
and replace -Dconfig.location by --spring.config.location

Answer (score 0):

Give full path of your application.properties file if you want to load it from outside the Jar

Comment: I tried this but it was not the good solution

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason :
I have to use :

> su sbert -c

instead of

> su - sbert -c